# Открыть изображение Qt

Tags: qt

Как при нажатии кнопки открыть изображение на всё окно и после его закрытия(изображения) вернуться обратно?

Comment: 1) Добавить картинку на QLabel (https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop) 2) Сказать QLabel развернуться на весь экран (https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#showFullScreen) 3) Поддержать закрытие, например при клике на Escape

Comment: А можно, чтобы изображение изначально не было видно?

Comment: Можно, например картинку не добавлять на QLabel, т.е. не вызывать у него setPixmap. Или добавить на qlabel, но его сделать невидимым (hide() или setVisible(false))